# Power Automate Flow | Sending email every first Monday of every month

Tags: email, power-automate, recurrence

Fairly new to Power Automate flows, so I need some help in creating a flow that will send an e-mail in Outlook to a certain set of 3 or 4 people every first Monday of every month. The e-mail contents will be the same every time. If the responders could please upload pictures of which connectors in their respective order, that would be great! Thanks!

I know there is a way to list out the exact dates in a column in Excel and use that as a connector for when the email should be sent, however this will be an ongoing process and want an automatic way for the flow to run without me having to update an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: [Schedule Power Automate flow to run only first Tuesday of the month](https://tomriha.com/schedule-power-automate-flow-to-run-only-first-tuesday-of-the-month/)

Answer (score 0):

If you write something like this in the "Code View" of the Recurrende-trigger, it should run once per month on monday:

```
{
  "type": "Recurrence",
  "recurrence": {
    "frequency": "Month",
    "interval": 1,
    "startTime": "2024-01-01T09:00:00Z",
    "timeZone": null,
    "schedule": {
      "weekDays": [
        "Monday"
      ],
      "hours": [
        "9"
      ],
      "minutes": null
    }
  }
}
```

When it is a new month, it will check if it is a monday, and run if it is. then it will wait untill next month.

Alternatively, you could run it every week and add a condition that it only continues if "today" is between the 1st and 7th day of the month, in addition to being a monday:
[image]

(This assumes that your format has monday as the first day of the week)